# SparklyR wrapper for spark SQL: sqlContext.sql

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr, r-dbi

I am trying to write a wrapper for SQL function for SparklyR. I have created the following function:

```
sqlfunction <- function(sc, block) {
  spark_context(sc) %>% 
invoke("sqlContext.sql", block) }
```

Then I call it using the following:

```
newsqlData <- sqlfunction(sc, "select
                          substr(V1,1,2),
                          substr(V1,3,3),
                          substr(V1,6,6),
                          substr(V1,12,4),
                          substr(V1,16,4)
                          FROM TABLE1 WHERE V1 IS NOT NULL")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid method sqlContext.sql for object 12
at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:113)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:89)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:55)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:49)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any suggestions or fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
sqlfunction <- function(sc, block) {
  spark_session(sc) %>% invoke("sql", block)
}
```

where `sc` is `spark_connection` (the output from: `spark_connect(master = master_url)`).

This:

- `spark_session(sc)` - retrieves `SparkSession` from the connection object.
- `invoke("sql", block)` - calls `sql` method of the `SparkSession` instance with `block` as an argument.

with example usage:

```
library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local[*]")
sqlfunction(sc, "SELECT SPLIT('foo,bar', ',')")
```

```
<jobj[11]>
  class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
  [split(foo,bar, ,): array<string>]
```

This will give you a reference to Java object. If you want you can for example register is as a temporary table:

```
... %>% invoke("createOrReplaceTempView", "some_name_for_the_view")
```

and access with `tbl`:

```
library(dplyr)

tbl(sc, "some_name_for_the_view")
```

or

```
... %>% sdf_register()
```

to get `tbl_spark` object directly.

Code you use:

- `spark_context` - extracts `SparkContext` instance.
- `invoke("sqlContext.sql", block)` - tries to call non-existent method (`sqlContext.sql`).

In the latest versions you can replace `invoke("createOrReplaceTempView", ...)` with simple `sdf_register`.